# how to integrate my app into the bb10 file manager?

Tags: blackberry-10

I would like to integrate my app into the standard BB10 file manager (like DropBox or OneDrive does).

[image]
Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drives that you mention are special cases, hard coded into the file manager application. Currently there is no way to integrate with the file manager in such a way.